# Set up UITabBarController with three other view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` inside of a `TabBarViewController`. I want to use this to connect my three other view controllers to a tab bar.

What I have so far: I have my three view controller, each with one `UIView` inside of them, ready to be paired with the tab bar to give easy navigation between them. I have also made a new Objective-C class of type `UITabBarController`. Inside the .xib of that I deleted the `UIView` and replaced it with a `UITabBarController` (not sure if this is right).

I'm new to Objective-C and Xcode so I don't know a whole deal about it all, so I may be doing this all wrong. Please correct me and try not to be too vague, thank you!

Comment: You have a UITabBarController inside of a TabBarViewController... Interesting... or written mistakenly..?

Comment: I'm not really sure; I made a class of type UITabBarController, and dragged a 'Tab Bar Controller' from the object library? Please fix if it is wrong

Comment: Here's a really good tutorial for UITabbarControlled app... http://simplecode.me/2011/12/05/tab-based-ios-apps-uitabbarcontroller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tutorial here with two tabs:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfEK9JsCyXM

You can watch it and work with it to make it do 3 tabs.